# Lync 2010, Kamailio, & Trixbox 2.6.23 (Asterisk 1.4)

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip, lync, trixbox

I'm having an issue trying to connect Lync 2010 phone calls with our trixbox PBX.  I've gotten to the point where Kamailio seems to be functioning properly and acting as a bridge between TCP traffic (from Lync) & UDP traffic (to the trixbox, as Asterisk 1.4 does not support SIP over TCP).

Our Lync box IP: 10.100.10.41
Our Kamailio box IP: 10.100.10.44
Our trixbox IP: 10.100.10.2

The issue I'm running into is as follows when enabling SIP debugging for the Kamailio box:

```
<--- SIP read from 10.100.10.44:5060 --->
PRACK sip:TNECLTSLY01.contoso.com:5068;transport=Tcp;maddr=10.100.10.41 SIP/2.0
FROM: <sip:9121;ext=4121@TNECLTSLY01.contoso.com;user=phone>;epid=CF2380792B;tag=4852bab430
TO: <sip:+4010@10.100.10.44;user=phone>;epid=CF2380792B;tag=3684a6a24e
CSEQ: 24 PRACK
CALL-ID: 192daae6-00e1-4140-bddd-0394b35d475b
MAX-FORWARDS: 70
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.100.10.44;branch=z9hG4bKcydzigwkX;i=d
VIA: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.100.10.41:51677;branch=z9hG4bK159fc989
CONTACT: <sip:TNECLTSLY01.contoso.com:5068;transport=Tcp;maddr=10.100.10.41>
CONTENT-LENGTH: 0
USER-AGENT: RTCC/4.0.0.0 MediationServer
RAck: 1 23 INVITE


<------------->
--- (12 headers 0 lines) ---
Sending to 10.100.10.44 : 5060 (NAT)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 10.100.10.44:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 481 Call leg/transaction does not exist
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.100.10.44;branch=z9hG4bKcydzigwkX;i=d;received=10.100.10.44
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.100.10.41:51677;branch=z9hG4bK159fc989
From: <sip:9121;ext=4121@TNECLTSLY01.contoso.com;user=phone>;epid=CF2380792B;tag=4852bab430
To: <sip:+4010@10.100.10.44;user=phone>;epid=CF2380792B;tag=3684a6a24e
Call-ID: 192daae6-00e1-4140-bddd-0394b35d475b
CSeq: 24 PRACK
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY
Supported: replaces
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
trixbox1*CLI>
<--- SIP read from 10.100.10.44:5060 --->
ACK sip:4010@10.100.10.44;user=phone SIP/2.0
FROM: "John Jones"<sip:9121;ext=4121@TNECLTSLY01.contoso.com;user=phone>;tag=4852bab430;epid=CF2380792B
TO: <sip:+4010@10.100.10.44;user=phone>;tag=3684a6a24e;epid=CF2380792B
CSEQ: 23 ACK
CALL-ID: 192daae6-00e1-4140-bddd-0394b35d475b
MAX-FORWARDS: 70
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.100.10.44;branch=z9hG4bKcydzigwkX;i=d
VIA: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.100.10.41:51677;branch=z9hG4bK79a21c
CONTENT-LENGTH: 0
```

My SIP trunk on the trixbox looks like this:

```
[from-lync]
exten => _+4XXX!,1,Noop(Stripping + from start of number) 
exten => _+4XXX!,n,Goto(from-internal,${EXTEN:1})
```

Though I am still having no luck getting the + stripped or the call to go through.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

-slashp